# How do I know the column values that will be inserted into a datasource table when using SQLDataAdapter.Update

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

I need to check the column's values that will be inserted into the data source database table before executing the `Insert` using a `SqlDataAdapter.Update` method.

Is the following command the right command?

```sql
scb.GetInsertCommand().Parameters["@ProductName"].Value.ToString(); -- scb is SqlCommandBuilder
```

it always throws a Null exception:

```
"unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred..."
```

which means @ProductName parameter has null value !!!

I don't give any value for any parameter. the column's values come from the `datagridview` which has a `datatable` as a source.

the insert process is always Succeeded but I need to check the inserted values before the insertion.

Comment: Why are you using ToString() when it is already a string?  You just need Parameters["@ProductName"].Value

Comment: if removed, it shows error.

Comment: Cast instead : (string)scb.GetInsertCommand().Parameters["@ProductName"].Value